# Connection failure error to cloud sql

Tags: java, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-sql

Sometimes, I am getting communication failure error when connecting with cloud SQL.Here is error details :

```
{ "error": {"errors": [   {
"domain": "global",    "reason": "backendError",
"message": "com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure\n\nThe last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server."   }  ],  "code": 503,  "message": "com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure\n\nThe last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server." }}
```

Please help me for this.

My java code is :

```
 Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");
con  = DriverManager.getConnection("<< connections , username,password>>");
java.sql.Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
String sqlpost = "<<  here is mysql query>>";
ResultSet rst = stmt.executeQuery(sqlpost);
int count = 0;
while (rst.next()) {
Users users = new Users(rst.getInt("id"), rst.getString("altername"));
friendlist.add(users);
}
con.close ();
```

Comment: Can you try to use a new connection before running your queries? The connection maybe idle long enough to cause that error.

Comment: I am calling multiple methods in 1 single function.  Everytime , i am making new connection in method and execute query , then response comes to function from method...what else i can do to avoid this error?

Comment: i tried to close connection before new connection will get open by con.close() method. it is working now.

Comment: Again , i am getting this issue sometimes...con.close() is not a solution to this error..please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: i have added java code , please have a look

Comment: Is the error throw at rst.next(), executeQuery, or somewhere else?

Comment: not getting where it exactly throws error..it simply execute whole and at last , shows communication failure error...